# preg_match (single quot) isn't working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I don't know why this code isn't working with me , I searched a lot but I couldn't find a solution 
I just need `preg_match` to accepts letters, single quot and space. 
Here is my code:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\-\' ]*$/",$firstName)) {
  $errors[] = "Invalid Name!"; 
}
```

for example if `$firstName = "abc'def"` this dosen't work!
thanks in advance.

NOTE:

There is `htmlspecialchars` before the regex check in the code.

Comment: You do not have a single quote in the pattern. Use `"/^[a-zA-Z' -]*$/"`

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add it here , but still not working even your way ! @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: It is working - http://ideone.com/o8pvWf, the `$firstName` is valid.

Comment: So why it's not working with me in localhost! is there a way to figure where is the error in `preg_match` ? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Is the `$firstName = "abc'def"` a real value? If you work with Unicode strings, you need to add `/u` modifier. I cannot help you until you describe *what does not work* or *how* your regex works.

Comment: What will happen if you modify your regex to `^[a-zA-Z\-\'\\ ]*$` with the same input?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this error is with any string that contains letters and single quot only (no number or especial character ,etc is used), `"abc'def"` was just an example

Comment: @revo Not working either ! :-(

Comment: You must have something like `htmlentities` before, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There is `htmlspecialchars` before

Comment: That is the culprit. `'` is converted to [*`&#039;` (for ENT_HTML401) or `&apos;` (for ENT_XML1, ENT_XHTML or ENT_HTML5), but only when ENT_QUOTES is set*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Can you move the regex check *before* that line? Else, you need to use an inefficient `/^(?:[a-zA-Z' -]|&(?:apos|#039);)*$/`

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't move it , So I used `if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\-\' ]*$/",htmlspecialchars_decode($company_name))` and still not working :-(

Comment: What about `html_entity_decode($company_name)` with `/^[a-zA-Z' -]*$/`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex `/^(?:[a-zA-Z' -]|&(?:apos|#039);)*$/` worked :) . but I don't understand why it didn't work when I used `htmlspecialchars_decode()` !

Comment: It will work if you pass the `ENT_QUOTES` as the second argument to the `htmlspecialchars_decode` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is the [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) that converts

> `'` to `&#039;` (for *ENT_HTML401*) or `&apos;` (for *ENT_XML1*, *ENT_XHTML* or *ENT_HTML5*), but only when *ENT_QUOTES* is set.

Solutions:

- Move the regex check *before* the `htmlspecialchars` conversion.
- Use an inefficient `/^(?:[a-zA-Z' -]|&(?:apos|#039);)*$/` pattern where the single quoted entities are included
- Decode the entities back (with `htmlspecialchars_decode($firstName,ENT_QUOTES)` or `html_entity_decode($firstName, ENT_QUOTES)`) and use your `/^(?:[a-zA-Z' -]*$/` regex on the "plain" value.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).